# Android - Set two Gravity parameters programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have button and want to change its text gravity to bottom center. How can I do that programmatically?

I can only find that I can change to center OR bottom, not both.

Comment: you need the "|" char to separate multiple values within the same tag.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try

```
setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know I can merge like that. Thanks

Comment: It's the usual way of combining flags using bitwise OR.

Comment: If this helped you it would be nice if you accepted this answer :)

Comment: `setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);` can we use like this ?

Can we mix both `CENTER_VERTICAL` and `CENTER_HORIZONTAL` ?

Comment: @NimmagaddaGowtham you'd just use `CENTER` in that case.

Answer (score 28):

In case you are wondering the *Kotlin version* it is

`your_button.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM or Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL`

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
 your_button.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

for more details below link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setGravity(int)